# How to locate silverlight controls to the same location when browsing?

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to create a login screen in silverlight and i was taken two textboxes and put them in two of rows in Grid layout but when i run the app textboxes taking right alignment and stick with end of the window right side, any one help me to get out of this.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With personal experience with Silverlight, i would recommend using blend 4 for these things.
Because it will give you a more direct feel and a look.
Most Grids can have a free form, so that you can put anything anywhere.Though if your just writing XAML for it you may be off on your padding and margins for the Textboxes in the the Grid.

Also if that's happening their is a Case where your TextBoxes may not be in the Grid, if that's the case it will try and throw it out of the picture but your canvas size is most likely set to the size of the Login Screen so it cant throw it out. Alas putting it in the right lower hand side.

I would definitely mess around with the different options inside blend to get that working,
if your a Windows Phone DEV then you should have blend 4...but if your a Silverlight WEB DEV you would have to download Sketch Flow or Blend 4 Ultimate.

Also if your a student you may access Dreamspark.com and get Ultimate for free.

I hope this helps! :)